# I have a img tag inside a ins tag , change the view that formatting of ins cover the image

Tags: css

I am new to HTML and CSS. I have an image inside a  tag:

```
<ins style="background-color: green; ">
     <img alt="image" src="image1.jpg">
</ins>
```

I can see the green line under the image only. What I want is that the green background color to apply to the whole image. So my entire image and the green color should be visible.
I tried on changing the width to 100% of its tag.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4U0z.png)]
I want to achieve this green color to apply to the whole image.

Comment: [https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=img&parent=ins](https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=img&parent=ins)

Comment: @Sfili_81 what's your point here? Nesting `img` into `ins` is perfectly valid in HTML5.

Comment: hum i'm not sure is semantica valid ( infact can i unclude says  Doubt?! EDIT: Sorry you are right, i don't see img in [phrasing-content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#phrasing-content-2)

Comment: In your question your image is a jpg so it has no transparent part through which the background color could show so I’m not sure what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi [@chirag gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16390715/chirag-gupta),

This is simple and I am adding a modified code since you're new to HTML and CSS.
Add style "position: absolute;" in the "ins" tag.

```html
<ins style="background-color: green;position: absolute;">
    <img alt="image" src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/apps/dota2/videos/dota_react/heroes/renders/faceless_void.png">
</ins>
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: [@chirag gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16390715/chirag-gupta), did you check the code above?